# Add signal - the result of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a query from two tables.
A table is "input" and the other "out". Wish list in the OUTPUT table appear with a plus sign ("-" Less) in shipping. That to get easier when listing values ​​that are positive and negative.

See my query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93dbcb/1

```
(SELECT nome, data, valor FROM `financ_receita` WHERE data BETWEEN ('2012-12-01') AND ('2013-12-23'))
    UNION ALL
(SELECT nome, data, valor FROM `financ_despesa` WHERE data BETWEEN ('2012-12-01') AND ('2013-12-23')) ORDER BY data ASC
```

financ_receita = input.

financ_despesa = out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it ?

```
select nome,data,if(valor<0,concat(valor),concat('+',valor)) as valor from 
(
 (
  SELECT nome, data, valor FROM `financ_receita` 
  WHERE data BETWEEN ('2012-12-01') AND ('2013-12-23')
 )
 UNION ALL
 (
  SELECT nome, data, valor*-1 FROM `financ_despesa`
  WHERE data BETWEEN ('2012-12-01') AND ('2013-12-23')
 ) 
 ORDER BY data ASC
) as myTable where valor != 0
```

Comment: It helped a lot, I just needed to know how to put the least. Ai with his help find that just needed to do so (valor*-1).

Thank you friend.